# Swift convert NSData to String

Tags: swift2

I have a NSData:

```
print("DEVICE TOKEN = \(deviceToken)")
```

containing the following:

```
DEVICE TOKEN = <19bd2388 88adb725 996437e3 cac6b7a5 7ba9157d 71bb5c00 ebee575f 255eca47>
```

when I'm trying to convert it using

```
String(data: deviceToken, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

my String is nil....but when I'm using the following:

```
String(data: deviceToken, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
```

I get this:

```
"\u{19}½#­·%d7ãÊÆ·¥{©\u{15}}q»\\\0ëîW_%^ÊG"
```

How can I get the real value of the NSData ?

Comment: If you're trying to get the hexadecimal String, you could just convert it to a String and then remove all non-hex characters, replacing the Regex `"[<> ]"` with `""`... For example, `try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[<> ]", options: NSRegularExpressionOptions()).stringByReplacingMatchesInString(String(token), options: NSMatchingOptions(), range: NSMakeRange(0, String(token).utf16.count), withTemplate: "")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content of `deviceToken` is just a series of bytes. It does not represent the byte layout of a string in any encoding. How you convert it to string is up to you.

You can concatenate the hex values together:

```
let str1 = deviceToken.description
            .stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
            .stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("<", withString: "")
            .stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(">", withString: "")
// Result: 19bd238888adb725996437e3cac6b7a57ba9157d71bb5c00ebee575f255eca47
```

Or use Base64 encoding (which I prefer because it can be easily converted back to `NSData`)

```
let str2 = deviceToken.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])
// Result: Gb0jiIittyWZZDfjysa3pXupFX1xu1wA6+5XXyVeykc=
```

Answer (score -2):

Please try this code, I hope this would be helpful

Swift

```
let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.description.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("<", withString: "").stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(">", withString: "").stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")

print(deviceTokenString)
```

ObjC

```
NSString * deviceTokenString = [[[[deviceToken description] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"<" withString: @""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @">" withString: @""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];
```